# RAII and assignment

Tags: c++, raii, assignment-operator

I created the following class for an sqlite3 connection:

```
class SqliteConnection
{
public:
    sqlite3* native;

    SqliteConnection (std::string path){
        sqlite3_open_v2 (path.c_str(), &native, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    }

    ~SqliteConnection (){
        sqlite3_close(native);
    }
}
```

and then one can initialize a connection as follows

```
SqliteConnection conn("./database.db");
```

However, I would like to be able to share this connection, store it as a member in classes, etc., and the trouble is with the default assignment operator `operator=`. Doing something like

```
SqliteConnection conn("./database.db");
SqliteConnection conn1 = conn;
```

would lead to two sqlite3_close calls on the database pointer as each variable goes out of scope. How do you overcome this difficulty with RAII when you need to assign your resource to a different variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For shared resources you will have to keep track of wether references to them exist, e.g. using [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). One implementation is [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) with a custom deleter:

```
class SqliteConnection {
    boost::shared_ptr<sqlite3> native;
public:
    SqliteConnection(const std::string& path) 
      : native(init_connection(path), &destroy_connection)
    {}
    // ...
};

sqlite3* init_connection(const std::string& path) {
    // ...
    return ptr;
}

void destroy_connection(sqlite3* p) {
    sqlite3_close(p);
}
```

Comment: looks like some extra garbage in your answer: the line `, destroy_connection())` doesn't seem to belong.

Answer (score 3):

Put the connection in a shared_ptr. On assignment all what you have to do is to assign "shared_ptr"s to have shared ownership of the resource(connection). Otherwise you have to implement shared ownership for your class which already has been done in boost and is included in C++0x.

Answer (score 0):

You have four basic options:

- Use reference counting, probably through a `shared_ptr`. This is the least efficient, but it's the most general solution.
- Prohibit assignments. Don't allow the user to copy the SQLite object. Make the assignment operator and copy constructors private. Then users will have to pass pointers or references around instead.
- Let assignment "steal" the resource. This is what `auto_ptr` does. `a = b` results in `a` taking ownership of `b`'s connection, and `b` being set to a null value, as an empty, unusable object.
- Create a new connection when a copy is created. This depends on the sqlite API providing the necessary functionality. In particular, queries and other connection-specific data may have to be copied as well, which might be impractical

Comment: You have named the options but you should also try and point which ones are appropriate and why.